# Как правильно сравнить время на разных временных зонах?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

Выполнено на моём сервере:

```
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);
+--------------------------------+
| TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP) |
+--------------------------------+
| 02:00:00                       |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@TIME_ZONE;
+-------------+
| @@TIME_ZONE |
+-------------+
| SYSTEM      |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`SYSTEM` у меня в `CET` (`UTC+2`)

Есть две даты в разных временных зонах

1. Server 1,Google Analytics (`GMT+1`): `2017-06-28 20:44:43`
2. Server 2, мой сервер (`UTC+2`): `2017-06-28 21:44:43`

> Временные зоны на серверах менять не надо.

Добавлял время на оба серверов одновременно:

```
<?php
    $created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    1) $created_at -> Google Analytics
    2) $created_at -> на мой сервер
```

Гарантии нет что завтра временные зоны не изменятся на серверах.По этому решил приводить их в `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` а потом сравнивать.

Реализовываю это следующим путём:

```
SELECT 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
CONVERT_TZ(
  '2017-06-28 15:44:43',
  '+02:00',
  @@session.time_zone
)
  ) = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
CONVERT_TZ(
  '2017-06-28 14:44:43',
  '+01:00',
  @@session.time_zone
)
  ) AS result
```

**Вопрос:** Правильно ли я все делаю, и является ли этот подход универсальным ?

Comment: Приведите всё время которое нужно сравнить в unix, и сравнивайте unix с unix - это будет правильно

Comment: @Daniil А вы вопрос до конца прочитали?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan А вы комментарий до конца мой прочитали?)

Comment: Он про другой метод спрашивает.

Comment: @Daniil Вопрос: Правильно ли я все делаю, и является ли этот подход универсальным ?

Answer (score 0):

Поле вида `TIMESTAMP` всегда хранится во зоне UTC. Только лишь видите вы его в текущей временной зоне:

```
mysql> SET time_zone = '+01:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> select ts from example limit 1;
+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2017-06-17 22:19:30 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SET time_zone = '+05:30';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> select ts from example limit 1;
+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2017-06-18 02:49:30 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

В это поле данные следует записывать *в текущей временной зоне*, а передавать между серверами в unixtime или в полном формате с указанием временной зоны (ISO 8601 или подобном).

Если вы используете такие поля (а не `DATETIME`), то вполне возможно что вам ничего не надо делать со стороны БД для решения вашей проблемы.